# PhoneGap or Titanium for UIQ3 develpoment?

Tags: cordova, titanium, uiq3

Is it possible to compile native uiq3 applications with .sis extension using titanium/phonepag ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appcelerator Titanium only supports iPhone and Android apps. Blackberry support is in progress but not finished now. (See [Appcelerator Website](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-mobile-application-development/)) There is no Symbian support.

PhoneGap supports more platforms including Symbian. (See [PhoneGap Website](http://www.phonegap.com/start))